# eclipse for users to access from terminal(like putty)

Tags: eclipse, putty

Here in our institute we have a server where student **login from putty** and write code -- need to create a file and write code in vi editor(generally they copy and paste code into vi editor), also one can upload files by ftp transfer (using Ammy admin). Coding lang's can be Java,Perl, ...

Here we need a eclipse environment to individual user to access their code from putty. where individual must be able to run, debug his code on server for which he connected through putty.

This is to reduce the time for the students for working on 2 environments, and also to maintain assignments in sever according to user.

Answer (score 0):

After you paste your code in Vi, you can run the program on server in debug-mode, with e.g.

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=suspend=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8123,server=y com.company.Main
```

and the program will listen on port 8123 until a debugger attaches to it,
and then you can remote debug it with Eclipse:

```
Run>Debug Configurations>double click "Remote Java Application">set project and host:port.
```

And you don't need putty for that, unless you are accessing the server through a ssh tunnel.

Eclipse do not support automatic code transfer to remote server, or starting program on remote server, 
the program must be started from the shell as shown above, and then eclipse can attach to it.

Comment: Thank you for responding, is this similar for perl also

Comment: I'm not a perl developer, anyway, it should be similar